# Cloud Connector problem. Cloud To On-Premise

Tags: sapui5

I created in SAP Logon OData Service and Registed it.

I cheked it and it works good. Now, I want to create cloud connector using the link which I got when tested my Odata Service. It looks like:

> http://mylink.com:1234/sap/opu/odata/sap/***_SRV/.

In cloud connector setting I put:

> Internal host:mylink.com
>
> Internal port:1234.

But, everytime when I try to check my connection in Cloud Connector it show to me ***Not Reachable***.

Can anybody advice to me something about that and explain to me the reasons of it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: could be firewall issue. if SCC is not allowed to communicate with your server

Answer (score 0):

Cloud connector requires two different addresses:

- Internal Host and port: this should be the real network address of your on premise system. Typically the SAP Netweaver Gateway where the service URL is in. The address must be reachable from the Cloud Connector server

  - Virtual Host and port: this should be a non real (virtual) address. **It’s a must** that this address **match** the URL address of a destination configured in SAP Cloud Platform.

Moreover, apart from the on premise configuration you must enable which URL paths are allowed to be accessed from the cloud

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your cloud connector and SAP LogOn OData service are in the same network. Then only the SAP cloud connector can reach your on-premise system through a secure channel.